# Python usersite directory points to file that doesn't exist

Tags: python, windows

I have downloaded and installed python modules before with no problem. Recently, however, none of the modules(They did install correctly) I have installed have been importable.

The modules installed where I expected them to - C:\Python27\lib\site-packages, and I have a .pth file created in that directory that points to each of the packages I want to be able to import.

The problem is that my site directory points to a file that doesn't exist: C:\Users\cam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages

By including the code

```
import site
site.addsitedir("C:\Python27\lib\site-packages")
```

However, I'd much rather just modify my site directories to point to that directory as well. I've looked around but have not found any way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried adding that path to your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: The user site-packages directory isn't created when Python is installed; it only gets create if you install packages using the `--user` option. Show the value of `sys.path` when you run Python normally.

Answer (score 0):

Add PYTHONPATH as system variable and add all the desired paths as values to that variable